# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a closure or failFast" Exception on running parallel builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline which has two parallel run in sequence. 
Setup in many slaves in parallel and after all the machine setup is done I have a Build and run stage as coded below. But when I tried running the script I am getting error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a closure or failFast but found 0=org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper`.
Code for reference:

```
def slaves = params.slaves

stage('Setup'){
    for(int i=0; i<slaves.size(); ++i){
        def slave = slaves[i]
        setup_builds[i] = build job: 'setup', parameters: [[$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'TestMachine', label: slave]]
    }
    parallel setup_builds
}
stage('Build, run) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        def index = i
        builds[i] = {
            stage('Build') {
                build job: 'Build'
            }

            stage('Run') {
               build job: 'Run', parameters: [string(name: 'index', value: index)]
            }
        }
    }

    parallel builds
}
```

I have tried using `setup_builds.failFast = true` and `builds.failFast = true` before `parallel setup_builds` and `parallel builds`. But even that didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think one of the issues is that it expects a closure on the setup_builds level:

```
setup_builds[i] =  { build job: 'setup' ... }
```

Comment: Thanks man I was missed the closure accidentally. The code inside the task worked fine, but in the end it gave me this error related to failfast exception. Had not idea where was the actual failure in the code.

Comment: Glad to help Mr. L.